# SQL JOIN to grab multiple tables with no relational criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, join

How can I use the SQL `JOIN` statement to simply grab data from multiple tables based on a `WHERE` clause rather than `ON` relational matching criteria?

I just want to grab rows from several tables by date:

So something like:

`SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3 WHERE date > '2020-01-01 00:00:00'`

The above wouldn't work obviously and I think a `JOIN` statement is in order but I'm not sure how to implement since I'm not looking to match data between the tables as would be the case with the `ON` directive.

To put it another way, I'm looking to replace the following 3 statements..

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE date > '2020-01-01 00:00:00'`

`SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE date > '2020-01-01 00:00:00'`

`SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE date > '2020-01-01 00:00:00'`

..with just a single statement.

Comment: I think you want to use [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html).

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor schema design

Comment: When you `JOIN` tables, you need relationship between those tables.  It doesn't make sense to join `product_category` to `country`.

Comment: @Strawberry it can but in this case its a symptom of poor management "can we create an aggregate view of all of our content types and sort it by date, no matter if the content is related or not?"

Comment: Fair enough then

Comment: "grab", "based on", "something like", etc don't mean anything. This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JOIN** is not for your situation. You should use **UNION** instead.
The only thing you should remember number of columns you select should be same for each select.
Here s example https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 UNION SELECT * FROM t2;
```

In your situation it will be

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE date > '2020-01-01 00:00:00' UNION

SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE date > '2020-01-01 00:00:00' UNION

SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE date > '2020-01-01 00:00:00';
```

Comment: You should be using and recommending `union all`, not `union`.